# How to display the contents of bootstrap modal tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a very beginner to AngularJS,I have a bootstarp modal with 2 tabs I have made it to display only one tab at a time.In the modal I have two buttons NEXT and PREVIOUS I am able to switch between the tabs through these buttons.But the issue is the content in their respective tabs wont change when I change the tab.Where am I going wrong.Kindly help me.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div role="tabpanel">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                <div>{{current.data}}</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="first" name="first" required></textarea>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="next()">next</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-click="previous()">previous</md-button>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="second" name="second" required></textarea>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="next()">next</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-warn md-raised" ng-click="previous()">previous</md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
         $scope.dataSet = [
              { data: "First", index: 0 },
              { data: "Second", index: 1 }   
         ],
         $scope.current = $scope.dataSet[0],
         $scope.next = function() {
             var i = $scope.getIndex($scope.current.index, 1);
             $scope.current = $scope.dataSet[i];
         },
         $scope.previous = function() {
             var i = $scope.getIndex($scope.current.index, -1);
             $scope.current = $scope.dataSet[i];
         },
         $scope.getIndex = function(currentIndex, shift) {
             var len = $scope.dataSet.length;
             return (((currentIndex + shift) + len) % len)
         }
});
```

Comment: <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> . Are you changing this href whenever you are changing tabs?

Comment: @slacker...am not changing href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code with the `ng-class` attribute for your selected data kindly refer https://jsfiddle.net/jasonantho/fwowg8q5/

Comment: @Joyson...This is what I actually wanted thank you for your asistance. Its working fine.